# "OR" query in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to find documents where the boxId field is not set or empty.

Running this does not work:

```
return Items.find({ createdBy: currenUser, boxId: { $or: [{ $exists: false }, { $size: 0 }] } })
```

Here's the error I get on the console:

```
Exception in template helper: Error: Unrecognized operator: $or
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering of mongodb key names and operators can often be confusing. Put the `$or` before the field conditions:

```
return Items.find({ createdBy: currentUser,
  $or: [
    { boxId: { $exists: false }},
    { boxId: "" }}
  ]
});
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error anymore, but it is not returning documents where the boxId field is "" (empty quotes). Is $size the right operator for this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9694397/2805154 for a related question and approach

Comment: My bad, I forgot to replace $size with your second condition. It works now. Thanks!